# Thread Safety and Scope Management for .NET 4.0 ObjectCache

Tags: asp.net, caching, .net-4.0, dependency-injection, thread-safety

I'm using the new .NET 4.0 Caching API, **[ObjectCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.aspx)**. I've asked a few questions on this area the last few days, and i've hinted to this issue - but thought it's worthwhile to break it out into it's own question.

Because the class is abstract and all the methods are virtual, this means we can create our own custom cache providers.

According to MSDN, `ObjectCache` does not have to be a singleton, and you can create multiple instances of it in your application.

But to me, this sounds like we need to manage the instantiation and lifetime of this object as well?

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application, with [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) as my dependency injection container.

I want to have a single, shared cache for my entire web application.

So, i create a very simple class which wraps the `ObjectCache` class, and provides the unboxing in the methods implementation.

The class takes an instance of `ObjectCache` in the ctor, and sets this to a **private static** instance of the cache, which the methods (Add, Get, etc) work off.

E.g

```
public class CacheManager
{
   private static ObjectCache _cache;

   public CacheManager(ObjectCache cache)
   {
      _cache = cache;
   }

   // Add, Get, Remove methods work off _cache instance.
}
```

Now, here's my DI registry:

```
For<CacheManager>().Singleton().Use<CacheManager>().Ctor<ObjectCache>("cache").Is(MemoryCache.Default);
```

In english: **When something requests a CacheManager instance, use a singleton instance, and set the ObjectCache parameter to be a MemoryCache instance.**

So there's what i have, now the questions:

1. If i have a class to wrap the `ObjectCache`, does this class need to be a singleton?
2. MSDN says `ObjectCache` is thread-safe, but now that i'm using a singleton, do i need any type of locking to keep the thread safety?
3. Does the private instance of `ObjectCache` in my wrapper class need to be static? Does the class itself need to be static?
4. General thoughts on my overall implementation?

I have not been able to find a decent blog/article on .NET ObjectCache in ASP.NET Web Applications, hence my confusion.

I'm use to using `HttpContext.Current.Cache` (which is static) and not care about lifetime management for the cache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Since `MemoryCache.Default` is a singleton, your stateless class doesn't really need to be one. However, that's completely up to you.
2. You should not need locking around the ObjectCache instance.
3. No, and No. Making it static doesn't provide any value. Indicating it's a singleton in StructureMap makes `GetInstance<>()` always return the same object anyways.
4. The real value of wrapping `ObjectCache` would to be abstract the cache implementation so you can change it or mock it. Without an interface this becomes less useful.

An example implementation below...

```
public interface ICacheManager
{
   // add, get, remove, etc
}

public class CacheManager : ICacheManager
{
   private static ObjectCache _cache;

   public CacheManager(ObjectCache cache)
   {
      _cache = cache;
   }

   // Add, Get, Remove methods work off _cache instance.
}
```

Then...

```
For<ICacheManager>()
    .Singleton()
    .Use<CacheManager>();

For<ObjectCache>()
    .Use(MemoryCache.Default);
```

If you want to change you cache provider that is still an `ObjectCache` in the future, then it's easy to adjust.

I hope this helps!

Comment: That's the answer i was looking for. Thanks. By the way - what makes you think `MemoryCache.Default` is a singleton?

Comment: And also, normally i would use an interface, but `ObjectCache` kind of is my interface, in that it's an abstract class. So if i want to flick over to another cache provider, i just change what type of `ObjectCache` gets injected into the ctor of the CacheManager class.

Comment: @Travis - any comments to the above?

Comment: An abstract class acts like an interface in this case, so that seems reasonable.

Comment: @Travis - what about your singleton comment? MSDN states otherwise, where did you decude it's a singleton?

Comment: MemoryCache.Default is a static property, effectively making it a singleton. Every reference will access the same value.

Comment: What if the property returns a new ObjectCache every time you call it?

Comment: @Linkgoron - well, ObjectCache is an abstract class, which means it can be instantiated. StructureMap instantiates the derived concrete class - MemoryCache, in a singleton fashion. So it is the same instance each time, i was just unsure if i needed the 'static' modifier on the actual implementation class. I think i've got enough info here. Thanks @Travis.

Comment: err sorry I wasn't clear. My response was to Travis. The fact that it's a static property doesn't mean that it returns the same object every time. In theory (o/c it depends on the implementation) it can return a new MemoryCache() every time you call .Default.

Comment: @Linkgoron, You are correct that in theory it could do that. Since it's a cache though, that wouldn't be useful since it wouldn't have access to the cached data unless you were connecting to something out of process; even then you'd want to pool connections so it would still likely not new up something every time. A normal pattern for new-ing something up like that would have a static factory method instead of just a static property as well.

Comment: @Travis I'm not saying it would be a SMART decision, or the best one. Just didn't want anyone seeing what you wrote and automatically thinking from now on that if they see a static property they'll 100% get the same object.

Comment: There are no guarantees, but version 4.0.0.0 is currently implemented as a singleton. I doubt they would change this behaviour in later versions, regardless of what the documentation says, because that would be a breaking change.